# What datetime class should I use for my case classes?

Tags: scala, datetime, playframework

I have case classes that may be used for representing models that originate from either a database table or API object.

Should I use joda or java.util.date or java.sql.date or?

This is for a playframework app, and I will use these models to display the datetime on the UI side of things where I will convert the date to the current users timezone also.

I'm just really confused.

Comment: If you are on JDK1.8 or later versions then you should definitely use java.time

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I am using 1.8 yes, care to expand on it further so I understand? :)  Will java.time support "2016-05-30T00:23:27.070Z" ?

Comment: java.time is the new time api provided in the JDK where java.util.Date is obsolete now.U will find it similar to Joda

Comment: This Question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Focus on your *specific* needs and situation.

Answer (score 3):

Agreeing with [the Answer by mkurz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38328485/642706)…

## java.time

Both `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`, and their related classes, have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Search Stack Overflow to learn more (after reading the Oracle Tutorial linked above). Many examples and discussions have been posted.

## Basic concepts

- Date-time handling is surprisingly tricky. Leave your intuition at the door.
- Strings are *not* date-time values; they are a *representation* of date-time values. Focus on using objects, not strings.
- You may work with a date-only, a time-only, or a date-time.
- Know that [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_offset) is just a number of hours/minutes/seconds while a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is a superset, adding rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). Use `OffsetDateTime` for one, and `ZonedDateTime` for the other.
- [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard provides sensible formats when parsing & generating Strings to represent date-time values.
- The “Local…” types mean “no specific locality”. These have no meaning, are not points on the timeline, until you specify the context of a specific time zone.
- The 3-4 letter abbreviations such as `EST` or `IST` you commonly see in the media are *not* time zones, are not standardized, and are not unique(!). [Proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) are `continent/region`.
- Apply a time zone for presentation to the user, but most of your business logic, data storage, and data exchange should be in UTC (the `Instant` class).

## Tips

- While programming, forget about your own local time zone. Think in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).
- Learn to read & write 24-hour clock times.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend http://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html

It works really nicely with play's json formatters and comes with a ton of helpers.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `java.time.ZonedDateTime` which was introduced in Java 8 and should be used for representing date and time related information that have a timezone. You can save values like `2016-05-30T00:23:27.070Z` with it. There is no need to use a third party library like joda time anymore (maybe in other cases there is, but not in your's)

(Do not use `java.util.Date` - most of it's methods are deprecated, for good reasons)

Answer (score 0):

As a blogger saied:
「Scala does not have a datetime package, but we can use the ones provided by Java.

Java 8 provides a better data/time API, so 3rd-party libraries like Joda-Time is no longer required.」

Here is the blog: 
https://www.hackingnote.com/en/scala/datetime

This will be helpful to you.